# Posting a form multiple time to a hidden iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, iframe

Here is my form:

```
<FORM id="webgrants" NAME="webgrants" action="updateDashPermissions.do" method="post" target="hidden-form">
<input type="hidden" name="property(userId)" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="property(dashboardSettings)" id="dashboardSettings" value="1">
</FORM>
```

After reading up on the submitting forms to hidden iframes, I realized I would need to delete and recreate the iframe each time I wanted to post the form. Here is the JavaScript to do that:

```
function deleteIframe() {
    $("#hidden-form").remove();
}

function sendSubmit() {  /*Called when checkbox checked*/

  var my_iframe = $('<IFRAME style="display:none" name="hidden-form" id="hidden-form"></IFRAME>');
  $('body').append(my_iframe);
  document.forms[0].submit();
  var t = setTimeout(deleteIframe, 2000);
}
```

However, the hidden iframe is not being removed and only the most recent form submission is being processed. Is there a way to remove the iframe so the form will submission will be processed? Or is there a more efficient way to post the same form multiple times to an iframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do the same by using regular Form element, by using JQuery, without the need of iFrame at all.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>     
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<form action="updateDashPermissions.do" method="post" id="searchForm">
  <input type="text" name="s" placeholder="Search...">
  <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
<!-- the result of the search will be rendered inside this div -->
<div id="result"></div>

<script>
// Attach a submit handler to the form
$( "#searchForm" ).submit(function( event ) {

  // Stop form from submitting normally
  event.preventDefault();

  // Get some values from elements on the page:
  var $form = $( this ),
    term = $form.find( "input[name='s']" ).val(),
    url = $form.attr( "action" );

  // Send the data using post
  var posting = $.post( url, { s: term } );

  // Put the results in a div
  posting.done(function( data ) {
    var content = $( data ).find( "#content" );
    $( "#result" ).empty().append( content );
  });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Or even simpler method is to use JQuery.POST to post any data to your server side "updateDashPermissions.do".

```
$.post( "updateDashPermissions.do", { userID: "John", dashboardSettings: "2pm" } );
```

Or you can Use a JQuery Plugin "jQuery Form Plugin" , This Plugin allows you to easily and unobtrusively upgrade HTML forms to use AJAX. The main methods, ajaxForm and ajaxSubmit, gather information from the form element to determine how to manage the submit process. Both of these methods support numerous options which allows you to have full control over how the data is submitted. Submitting a form with AJAX doesn't get any easier than this!

http://jquery.malsup.com/form/

references:

- https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/
- http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: The first code segment didn't work, but the second worked perfectly. Thank you!